# round BigDecimal to nearest 5 cents

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to figure out how to round a monetary amount upwards to the nearest 5 cents. The following shows my expected results

```
1.03     => 1.05
1.051    => 1.10
1.05     => 1.05
1.900001 => 1.10
```

I need the result to be have a precision of 2 (as shown above).

### Update

Following the advice below, the best I could do is this

```
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(990.49)

    // To round to the nearest .05, multiply by 20, round to the nearest integer, then divide by 20
   def result =  new BigDecimal(Math.ceil(amount.doubleValue() * 20) / 20)
   result.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

I'm not convinced this is 100% kosher - I'm concerned precision could be lost when converting to and from doubles. However, it's the best I've come up with so far and *seems* to work.

Comment: By definition, you're losing precision anyway since you're rounding.  I don't think you have too much to worry about with regard to precision loss.

Comment: As an aside, if you are worried about the precision, then you should create your BigDecimals using the String constructor, not the double constructor.

Comment: See @marcolopes answer for how to do it with `BigDecimal` without using `doubleValue()`.

Comment: 1:051 rounds to 1.05, not 1.10.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use plain double to do this.

```
double amount = 990.49;
double rounded = ((double) (long) (amount * 20 + 0.5)) / 20;
```

EDIT: for negative numbers you need to subtract 0.5

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html  "As mentioned above, this data type [double] should never be used for precise values, such as currency."

Comment: @daemonl A good quote, except that most trading systems use double or long, especially those using C++.

Comment: @PeterLawrey source for this statement? I have never ever seen such a system, but I've worked with PL/I, C, and C++ systems in banks and other institutions...

Comment: @D.Kovács which data type did they use?  I have consulted for more than half the big banks in London and New York on these systems.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The systems I have encountered always used self-built data structures for storing monetary data. I don't say this as an absolute, just stating that using plain `double` is a very, very, *VERY* bad idea.

Comment: @D.Kovács I can understand developers not being comfortable with using `double` and it has it's quirks but in investment banks, they rarely use anything else.

Comment: @PeterLawrey interesting, I currently work in the insurance sector with Java, and everything is in BigDecimal...

Comment: @D.Kovács I have worked on systems which are all BigDecimal. My first year of consulting was basically paid for by replacing BigDecimal with double for various clients, so I owe a lot to it ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Genuinely interested to know how you did this without introducing rounding errors. Why are Oracle wrong to say double should never be used for precise values, such as currency?

Comment: @DavidEasley there is a myth that you don't need to worry about rounding. It is rare that your operations are always so simple you never need to worry about rounding. Even if you use BigDecimal you need to get rounding right. The "nice" thing about double is it us often obviously wrong e.g 0.9999999999999998 but BigDecimal might be 0.99. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: @DavidEasley in the case above, when you have two values which are represented without error and you perform an operation you get the nearest representable value to the result. As long as you are not working to the limits of the precision of double this isn't a problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for responding but you're still giving us rather vague, handwavy answers. There are many references on the net to the danger of using floating point for things like currency, i.e. where precision is critical. Please can you point to just one reference (ideally a reputable one) that backs up your assertion that floating point (or at least double) is fine for financial calculations.

Comment: @DavidEasley I would point to the IEEE-754 spec which explains exactly how it works in a consistent and predictable manner. What you consider reputable is purely a matter of opinion, I can tell you that the reality is that most investment banks use `double` in Java, and you can chose not to believe me if you like. Projects using BigDecimal have made me a lot of consulting money over the years, so please keep using it if you prefer it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, so that's why invesment banking has more problem than it should.

Comment: @D.Kovács when a bank loses $84 billion in a quarter it wasn't a rounding error :P I was at bank which did this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "I was" - and we know why the past tense ;) Joking apart: no that was a very elaborate hack. If we are talking about the same event. But in the case I have in my mind, it wasn't one bank but several. So maybe it's another :)

Answer (score 77):

Using `BigDecimal` without any doubles (improved on the answer from marcolopes):

```
public static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal increment,
                               RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    if (increment.signum() == 0) {
        // 0 increment does not make much sense, but prevent division by 0
        return value;
    } else {
        BigDecimal divided = value.divide(increment, 0, roundingMode);
        BigDecimal result = divided.multiply(increment);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The rounding mode is e.g. `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`. For your examples, you actually want `RoundingMode.UP` (`bd` is a helper which just returns `new BigDecimal(input)`):

```
assertEquals(bd("1.05"), round(bd("1.03"), bd("0.05"), RoundingMode.UP));
assertEquals(bd("1.10"), round(bd("1.051"), bd("0.05"), RoundingMode.UP));
assertEquals(bd("1.05"), round(bd("1.05"), bd("0.05"), RoundingMode.UP));
assertEquals(bd("1.95"), round(bd("1.900001"), bd("0.05"), RoundingMode.UP));
```

Also note that there is a mistake in your last example (rounding 1.900001 to 1.10).

Comment: Clearly the best answer. Please upvote so it's ranked higher than those hacky solutions that use floating point.

Comment: @DavidEasley I can understand developers not feeling comfortable using language primitives and operations like double, but that doesn't make using them hacky.

Comment: They are not literally hacky but they only work on BigDecimals small enough to fit into double. Therefore they are not reliable solutions. This one works on any BigDecimal.

Comment: Using BigDecimal is much more expressive of the fact that you're manipulating currency amounts.

Comment: this one is the perfect answer and solves my problem.

Answer (score 11):

I'd try multiplying by 20, rounding to the nearest integer, then dividing by 20.  It's a hack, but should get you the right answer.

Comment: Not a hack at all, a perfectly sound technique.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote this in Java a few years ago: https://github.com/marcolopes/dma/blob/master/org.dma.java/src/org/dma/java/math/BusinessRules.java

```
/**
 * Rounds the number to the nearest<br>
 * Numbers can be with or without decimals<br>
 */
public static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal rounding, RoundingMode roundingMode){

    return rounding.signum()==0 ? value :
        (value.divide(rounding,0,roundingMode)).multiply(rounding);

}


/**
 * Rounds the number to the nearest<br>
 * Numbers can be with or without decimals<br>
 * Example: 5, 10 = 10
 *<p>
 * HALF_UP<br>
 * Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless
 * both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.
 * Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is >= 0.5;
 * otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN.
 * Note that this is the rounding mode commonly taught at school.
 */
public static BigDecimal roundUp(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal rounding){

    return round(value, rounding, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

}


/**
 * Rounds the number to the nearest<br>
 * Numbers can be with or without decimals<br>
 * Example: 5, 10 = 0
 *<p>
 * HALF_DOWN<br>
 * Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless
 * both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down.
 * Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5;
 * otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN.
 */
public static BigDecimal roundDown(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal rounding){

    return round(value, rounding, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);

}
```

Comment: I think using `rounding.signum() == 0` would be a better test for 0 instead of `rounding.doubleValue() == 0`. Apart from that, this solution is good.

Comment: Thanks! Thats correct... this code is old and i was new to java! :D signum() is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of very simple methods in c# I wrote to always round up or down to any value passed.

```
public static Double RoundUpToNearest(Double passednumber, Double roundto)
    {

        // 105.5 up to nearest 1 = 106
        // 105.5 up to nearest 10 = 110
        // 105.5 up to nearest 7 = 112
        // 105.5 up to nearest 100 = 200
        // 105.5 up to nearest 0.2 = 105.6
        // 105.5 up to nearest 0.3 = 105.6

        //if no rounto then just pass original number back
        if (roundto == 0)
        {
            return passednumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.Ceiling(passednumber / roundto) * roundto;
        }
    }
    public static Double RoundDownToNearest(Double passednumber, Double roundto)
    {

        // 105.5 down to nearest 1 = 105
        // 105.5 down to nearest 10 = 100
        // 105.5 down to nearest 7 = 105
        // 105.5 down to nearest 100 = 100
        // 105.5 down to nearest 0.2 = 105.4
        // 105.5 down to nearest 0.3 = 105.3

        //if no rounto then just pass original number back
        if (roundto == 0)
        {
            return passednumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.Floor(passednumber / roundto) * roundto;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala I did the following (Java below)

```
import scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode

def toFive(
   v: BigDecimal,
   digits: Int,
   roundType: RoundingMode.Value= RoundingMode.HALF_UP
):BigDecimal = BigDecimal((2*v).setScale(digits-1, roundType).toString)/2
```

And in Java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public static BigDecimal toFive(BigDecimal v){
    return new BigDecimal("2").multiply(v).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).divide(new BigDecimal("2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, another possible solution would be:

```
BigDecimal twenty = new BigDecimal(20);
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(990.49)

// To round to the nearest .05, multiply by 20, round to the nearest integer, then divide by 20
BigDecimal result =  new BigDecimal(amount.multiply(twenty)
                                          .add(new BigDecimal("0.5"))
                                          .toBigInteger()).divide(twenty);
```

This has the advantage, of being guaranteed not to lose precision, although it could potentially be slower of course...

And the scala test log:

```
scala> var twenty = new java.math.BigDecimal(20) 
twenty: java.math.BigDecimal = 20

scala> var amount = new java.math.BigDecimal("990.49");
amount: java.math.BigDecimal = 990.49

scala> new BigDecimal(amount.multiply(twenty).add(new BigDecimal("0.5")).toBigInteger()).divide(twenty)
res31: java.math.BigDecimal = 990.5
```

Answer (score 0):

For this test to pass :

```
assertEquals(bd("1.00"), round(bd("1.00")));
assertEquals(bd("1.00"), round(bd("1.01")));
assertEquals(bd("1.00"), round(bd("1.02")));
assertEquals(bd("1.00"), round(bd("1.024")));
assertEquals(bd("1.05"), round(bd("1.025")));
assertEquals(bd("1.05"), round(bd("1.026")));
assertEquals(bd("1.05"), round(bd("1.049")));

assertEquals(bd("-1.00"), round(bd("-1.00")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.00"), round(bd("-1.01")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.00"), round(bd("-1.02")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.00"), round(bd("-1.024")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.00"), round(bd("-1.0245")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.05"), round(bd("-1.025")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.05"), round(bd("-1.026")));
assertEquals(bd("-1.05"), round(bd("-1.049")));
```

Change `ROUND_UP` in `ROUND_HALF_UP` :

```
private static final BigDecimal INCREMENT_INVERTED = new BigDecimal("20");
public BigDecimal round(BigDecimal toRound) {
    BigDecimal divided = toRound.multiply(INCREMENT_INVERTED)
                                .setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal result = divided.divide(INCREMENT_INVERTED)
                               .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static BigDecimal roundTo5Cents(BigDecimal amount)
  {
    amount = amount.multiply(new BigDecimal("2"));
    amount = amount.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    // preferred scale after rounding to 5 cents: 2 decimal places
    amount = amount.divide(new BigDecimal("2"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return amount;
  }
```

Note that this is basically the same answer as [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574187/1124509).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void roundUp()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the currency : $");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String myint = keyboard.next();
        if (!isEmptyOrBlank(myint).booleanValue())
        {
            BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(myint);
            System.out.println("Enter the round up factor: $");
            String roundUpFactor = keyboard.next();
            if (!isEmptyOrBlank(roundUpFactor).booleanValue())
            {
                BigDecimal scale = new BigDecimal(roundUpFactor);
                BigDecimal y = d.divide(scale, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
                BigDecimal q = y.setScale(0, 0);
                BigDecimal z = q.multiply(scale);
                System.out.println("Final price after rounding up to " + roundUpFactor + " is : $" + z);
                System.out.println("Want to try with other price Y/N :");

                String exit = keyboard.next();
                if ((!isEmptyOrBlank(exit).booleanValue()) && ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(exit))) {
                    roundUp();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("See you take care");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please be serious u r dealing with critical Tx Pricing");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Please be serious u r dealing with critical Tx Pricing enter correct rounding off value");
    }
}
```

Comment: This pseudo takes inputs from line command where you can enter the value to round up along with round up value i.e. Enter the currency : $
1.051
Enter the round up factor: $
0.05
Final price after rounding up to 0.05 is : $1.10

Answer (score -1):

Tom has the right idea, but you need to use BigDecimal methods, since you ostensibly are using BigDecimal because your values are not amenable to a primitive datatype.  Something like:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(0.23);
BigDecimal twenty = new BigDecimal(20);
//Might want to use RoundingMode.UP instead,
//depending on desired behavior for negative values of num.
BigDecimal numTimesTwenty = num.multiply(twenty, new MathContext(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)); 
BigDecimal numRoundedUpToNearestFiveCents
  = numTimesTwenty.divide(twenty, new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
```

Comment: This throws an exception

    Exception thrown: Rounding necessary
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary