# Java round off 0.05 for money

Tags: java, formatting, rounding

I have 7.125 (double), need to make it 7.15. What could be the easiest way?

Found round up, but am getting 7.13, please help.

thanks

Comment: The best way would be not using `double` for money. 
Use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) Also, you are asking for rounding based on custom rules. I guess you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: You are overcharging the customer :0

Comment: What kind of rounding mode is that :o

Comment: And why would you need that rounding rule? Would -7.125 also be rounded to -7.15? And what about other values like 7.105, 7.155 or 7.175?

Comment: @user802421: Many currencies work like that, as there are no coins smaller than `0.05`. For example: CHF

Comment: possible duplicate of [round BigDecimal to nearest 5 cents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106615/round-bigdecimal-to-nearest-5-cents)

Comment: @Reno - there are a variety of countries that have no 1c denominations (like Singapore) ... and they require rounding to the nearest 5c (most merchants round down, but not all)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to multiply by `20.0`, round to integers and divide by `20.0` again. Think of it this way: `1.0 / 20.0 = 0.05`... That's why this will work.

Note, "rounding" is not the same as "flooring" (or casting to `int`). You should use `java.lang.Math.round()` for `double` and `float` types, or `java.math.BigDecimal.round(MathContext)` for `BigDecimal` types

You might be better off using `BigDecimal` for this

Comment: 7.125 * 20 = 142.5; 142 / 20 = 7.1; 7.1 == 7.15?

Comment: @user802421: Rounding (not flooring/truncating) `142.5` will result in `143`, not `142`

Comment: Are you sure? It's depend on rounding mode. (int)142.5 = 142

Comment: @user802421: Casting is not rounding, but flooring. Check out `java.lang.Math.round(double)`

Comment: Math.round() has on specific rounding mode.

Comment: @Lukas: Thanks, it works. But for 0.5625 ==> 11.25 ==> 11.0 ==> 0.55 But I need 0.6, can you please tell me, how this works? I used Math.round()

Comment: That appears correct to me, except you *DO* want to rip off your customers :-) Are you speaking about "rounding" or "rounding up"? Rounding up can be achieved with `java.lang.Math.ceil()`

Comment: :) It is just tax calculation

Comment: OK, taxes. So you *DO* want to rip off your "customers" ;-) anyway. Rounding up means `0.5625 -> 0.6` (`Math.round()`), Rounding means `0.5625 -> 0.55` (`Math.ceil()`)

Comment: @Vanathi and Lukas: Generally, money is always rounded up to the nearest penny anyway so 0.5xyyyyyy~ where y in the least (most? I can never remember) significant digit is greater than zero results in 0.5x+1. Example: Three items at 0.33 cents with 8.25% tax added = 0.357225 * 3 = 1.071675. Establishments can't charge you 0.001675 of a dollar and they *darn* sure don't want to lose a dollar every ten customers, so 1.071675 becomes the 1.08.

Comment: @Casey: That depends on so many facts, there is no such thing as "generally" when money is concerned, believe me. Just look at the various stock exchanges and their respective tradable securities. Many securities have an associated rounding lot. Some securities even have weird rounding lots such as `0.1429 [some currency]`, which means you have to round values up/down to `1/7`. When accounting and taxes are involved, most jurisdictions in any country settle calculation rules by laws, so it doesn't make sense to make assumptions here... if rounding to `0.05` is needed, there's probably a reason

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to round up to the nearest .05 is the following.

```
int ans = java.lang.Math.round((7.125 / 0.5)) * 0.5
```

This works with any increments you would like to round by. Just change the 0.5 in the equation.

Answer (score -4):

Floor the value then add 0.15?

Comment: And how would your algorithm round `7.325`? ;-)