# Rounding price to the nearest multiple of 5cent in java

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

I'm new to java programming. I would like to round up a price to the nearest 2 decimal places.

E.g.

38.82 into 38.80
38.87 into 38.90
38.85 stays the same.
I did the E.g. 1 and E.g. 2 but it comes out only 1 decimal place. E.g. 38.82 to 38.8

this is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RoundUp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double num = 38.84;
        System.out.println(df.format(Math.round(num*10.00)/10.00));
    }
}
```

I have looked into other model answers by experts in this web but none of it really answer my question. Setting into 2 decimal places, I'm using DemicalFormat. That I know, but rounding the number, let's say 38.83 to 38.85 and 38.87 to 38.90 is what I really want. It is a rounding system that my country is using. Can check it out [here](http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=en_rounding&pg=en_rounding_content&ac=567).

And please everybody.. please don't change my question to a duplicate one. you think that its a duplicated one, please ask me for more info. I can ensure you that it is not a duplicated (I think...)

Comment: `Math.round(num*20.00)/20.00)`

Comment: This has been answered before. But don't go by the accepted answer. Use the most voted up answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106615/round-bigdecimal-to-nearest-5-cents

Comment: hi @Bobby, i tried the BigDecimal.. even use the ROUND_UP methods.. it doesnt round up the numbers.. but instead i went up by 1 cent
Eg. 38.83 ->38.84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert the price to cents, divide by 5, round to, multiply by 5 again and convert back to dollars:

```
double rounded = Math.round(num * 100.0 / 5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;
```

Comment: :- could you please tell me how did you come out with this answer??

Comment: I hope you are at least calculating yourself `100.0 / 5.0` As [Jesper](wrote), this could be written `Math.round(num * 20.0) / 20.0`, sparing some useless calculus for the computer. A [more generic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16665378/1734119) also exists on a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

When you deal with money, you should avoid using float or double variables and use an integer datatype instead in order to avoid problems due to the fact that calculations with float or double values are not exact.

You could use the following solution (when dealing with int):

```
public static int roundUp(int cents) {
    int centsMod5 = cents%5;
    if (centsMod5 > 0) {
        cents += (5 - centsMod5);
    }
    return cents;
}
```