# Round a number to 5 cents up in java

Tags: java, rounding

I'm trying to figure out how to round a monetary using this Rules:

```
 Tax calculated | Taxe imputed |
|---------------|--------------|
|          0.99 |         1.00 |
|          1.00 |         1.00 |
|          1.01 |         1.05 |
|          1.02 |         1.05 |
```

I tried various methods for rounding but always I get an error:

I have 2 books at 12.49€ with tax 10%; 
and one cd at 14.99€ with tax 20%

I tryied this method but always get false result

```
double number = 12.49 * 0.1 * 2;
double number2 = 14.99 * 0.2;
double round1 = Math.round(number * 100.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;
double round2 = Math.round(number2 * 100.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;
```

the console print 5.5 (round1+round2) but I should get 5.53

Help Please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round BigDecimal to nearest 5 cents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106615/round-bigdecimal-to-nearest-5-cents)

Comment: I tried this method but not working

Comment: @MajdiTaleb Try using BigDecimal and show the code which you claim is not working.

Comment: @Kan  same result 5.5 always instead of 5.53

Comment: Not your problem but important: Google "Don't use floats for money"

Comment: Why do you want 5.53? (12.49 + 14.99) * 0.2 = 5.496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **`(double)Math.round(value * 100000d) / 100000d`**

   That's for 5 digits precision. The number of zeros indicate the
   number of decimals.

   please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) (stack-overflow question) and
   [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) (oracle documentation)

   ```
   double round1 = Math.round(number * 100.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;
   double round2 = Math.round(number2 * 100.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 100.0;
   ```

   so , either you should reconsider the position of parenthesis
   (re-arrange the values) or please use another variable without round
   first and then do the round() operation.

   in this case simply,

   ```
   double round1 = Math.round(number * 1000.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 1000.0;
   double round2 = Math.round(number2 * 1000.0 /5.0) * 5.0 / 1000.0;
   ```

   might solve the problem , but it is better to do it properly , so
   that it will remain meaningful later.
2. Using  Decimal format for string output , eg.,

   ```
   double val=8.888888;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");//for 3 decimal places
   df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
   String value=df.format(val);
   ```

   for more info check [Class DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) , remember that it can be parsed to number , iff it is really necessary.